# Use wireshark to see requests, not packets

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to monitor calls to an API, and I am trying to do so with wireshark.  However, I only see low level packets, I want to see the actual http and https requests and responses.  Is this possible with wireshark?

Comment: What do you mean by "only see low level packets"?  For HTTP, Wireshark will show HTTP requests and responses but will also show low-level details (as it's a packet analyzer).  For HTTPS, you need to give Wireshark enough information to decrypt the encrypted SSL/TLS traffic in order to see the HTTPS requests and responses.

Comment: Thx for the reply. What I mean is, I don't see words, just bytes.  I want to see the equivalent of what I see in the Chrome network tab and it's not obvious how to decode those bytes into a set of readable requests.

Comment: For HTTP, you shouldn't be seeing just bytes; file a bug on that on [the Wireshark bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org) and attach a capture to it.  For HTTPS, you would, as I said, need to give Wireshark enough information to decrypt the traffic, if that's possible; at least for HTTPS, a proxy often works better for sniffing traffic, as it can capture it *before* it gets encrypted.

Comment: Hi, @user1130176 Did you ever figure this question out? If so, please recommend the tool and method to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using something besides `wireshark` for this.

For instance the [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/) proxy will allow you to inspect requests and responses between you and the application, as well as pause a request, edit it, then send it on it's way. It really is a great tool for working with web APIs.